# How to prevent to create database again from beginning

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a database like this:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "sorular"
                 + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                 + "soruIcerik TEXT," + " siklar1 TEXT," + " siklar2 TEXT,"
                 + " siklar3 TEXT," + "siklar4 TEXT," + "cevap INTEGER" 
                     + "zorluk INTEGER);");
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST sorular");
        onCreate(db);

}
```

After that I have added datas into database and I pushed the database onto emulator. But when I close and rerun the application, it creates the database again from beginning. so, my datas are deleted. How to prevent to this? What should I do?

Comment: What is the `version` number you pass in to superclass `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor?

Comment: `version` number is 1

Comment: "pushed the database onto emulator" - so you're editing the db using some tools? Make sure the [PRAGMA user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) value stays the same (it's that `version` number).

Comment: Yeah..I have been using SQLite Manager that is extension of Mozilla. How am I learn this PRAGMA user_version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on clarifying comments, it seems your SQLite database [`user_version`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) number gets overwritten when editing the database on another SQLite database manager. Android uses this field to store the `version` number passed in to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor and when upgrading a database from another version using `onUpgrade()` or `onDowngrade()`. By default the version is 0 so when using a version 1 `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you'll get an upgrade from version 0 to 1, which in your case destroys the data.

Some ways to mitigate the issue:

1. Only create and edit SQLite databases using Android helper classes.
2. Implement a non-destructive `onUpgrade()`, i.e. one that does not drop tables, only makes sure the required tables are there and migrates data from old tables if needed.
3. If using external database managers, issue `PRAGMA user_version=n;` SQL command to make sure the database version will be `n`. (Sorry, haven't used Mozilla's tool and cannot tell if and how it is possible there.)